# It is possible to load in web .net actual file from acount google using google docs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In my web project web .net I try to implement google docs.
I upload any MS office document and view it on telerik window by open window sets url: `entry.AlternateUri.ToString()`

Then I try to download file (if title is match) to local:

```
   myService = new DocumentsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
   myService.setUserCredentials("name_my_mail@gmail.com", "pass");
   DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
   DocumentsFeed feed = myService.Query(query);                   

                    foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.Title.Text == "temp.docx")
                        {
                            Uri documentUri = new Uri(entry.Content.AbsoluteUri);

                            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(documentUri);
                            GDataGAuthRequestFactory factory = (GDataGAuthRequestFactory)myService.RequestFactory;
                            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + factory.GAuthToken);

                            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\temp.txt");

                            string line = "";
                            while( (line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) {

                                   streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                            streamReader.Close();
                            streamWriter.Close();  
                        }
                    }
```

But file temp.txt contents actual html code of content file fron google acount.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out Google Docs API.

[DotNet API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html)

[General Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/documents/)

Hope that helps

Cheers

Sascha